# Annoying 'Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 24.' for image answers

Tags: feature-request

I propose we reduce or get rid of the 30 character requirement because some answers that are primarily images require little to no text. [example](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126294/using-accordion-lists-with-radio-buttons/126301#126301)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fundamentally disagree with this, I'm afraid.

A picture is not an answer, it's just a picture. Other than the accessibility issues an image doesn't give any reasoning as to *why* it solves it.

An image can be used as an *example* of how the issue has been solved, to support the description and text of the answer itself. The example you linked to is not a good answer, it's just a picture. It doesn't say why it's any better than the suggestion the question poster produced.

Think as if you were going into a meeting about the issue. Someone describes what their problem is. You wouldn't just go up to the whiteboard, sketch something up without saying anything and then walk out the room. You'd describe what you're drawing, why you're drawing it and why you think it would solve the problem.